# Can I use the "there is" construction for art exhibitions, instead of using the word "hold"?

Tags: grammar

As a sightseeing suggestion to my out-of-town friend, I want to say there's an exhibition he might be interested in checking out.

Option 1 below sounds too formal to me, so I'd like to know if Options 2 to 4 are grammatically OK.

1. A kimono exhibition is held at MoMA.
2. MoMA is having a kimono exhibition.
3. They are having a kimono exhibition at MoMA.
4. There is a kimono exhibition at MoMA.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: at first glance 2 - 4 look fine. I actually think 1 should be rephrased as 'A kimono exhibition is being held at MoMA' but I don't like it. Maybe 'MoMA are holding a kimono exhibition' sounds better.

Comment: Maybe the Tate Modern (in London) *are* holding such an exhibition, but MOMA in New York *is* holding it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Smock. I see why you think Option 1 needs to be in the progressive form ("A kimono exhibition is being held at MoMA"). You don't like it because it sounds formal (to the point of being awkward), right?
And "MoMA IS holding..." is incorrect? How about "The museum IS holding..."? Should it be "The museum are holding..."?

Comment: Thanks @remarki . I'm having trouble understanding the difference. Why the Tate Modern is plural and MoMA is singular? I'd appreciate any elaboration.

Comment: ah yes, maybe it should be 'is' I am unsure. The reason I didn't like 'A kimono exhibition is being held at MoMA' was more to do with being 'held' could also be interpreted as 'currently located at' but that would really apply to a specific exhibition or collection that was on tour perhaps (like a  travelling show). I'm completely unsure now - perhaps an answer will appear that will better define it.

Comment: @Richard The comment about *Tate Modern (in London)* ***are*** versus *MOMA in New York* ***is*** was a slightly veiled reference to the fact that UK English typically treats collectives as plural (*the board of directors* ***are*** *voting*) while US English typically treats them as singular (*the board of directors* ***is*** *voting*). In reality, I would *not* mix your grammar up that way in a single sentence. Stick with one or the other. Based on your example sentences, it should be *is*, if you use that construction.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for the explanation. I get it now! I had learned something like "The staff IS/ARE (Am/Br) well-trained," but didn't realize that was what was at work in the Tate vs MoMA case. Great to know; thank you so much!